# Importing winform solution to mono (linux) from VS Code (windows)

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I tried to import a winform solution file from VS code (windows) to monodevelop (Linux) but it failed. The error is as follows:

```
Error while trying to load the project '/home/virtuall_kingg/Camera_GUI/Camera_GUI/Camera_GUI.csproj': 
File not found: /home/virtuall_kingg/Camera_GUI/Camera_GUI/Camera_GUI.csproj
```

I added `Camera_GUI.csproj`file also but still the error is same.
Can anybody guide me on how to import solution to mono?
This winform project has become pain in my neck.
Is building the GUI using gtk# in Ubuntu from scratch is the only way?

Comment: As for your question, I'd be tempted to create a new (empty) project in MonoDevelop and then add all of your code files and references back in.

Comment: Don't waste your time on a dead end. Check alternatives, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea You also need to learn the differences of Linux file system.

Comment: @John I tried to import the solution from vscode to monodevelop.

Comment: @John Are you sure, that willhelp?

Comment: There's a `[visual-studio-code]` tag for VS Code and a `[visual-studio]` tag for Visual Studio. As for whether my suggestion helps: maybe, I'm not sure. It's just what I'd try to do.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Now you can substitute mono with .NET 5, the common .net framework for all platforms.

You are asking multiple questions here. In Linux you have (limited) support for *WinForms* through **Mono**. Depending on how complex is your project, you could port it without modification. If there are p/Invokes, then you won't for sure be able to port it.

Yep, in Linux the "other" big option is Gtk#, which has a long history. If you would want to port the project starting from scratch, it'd be a good option, but it'd involve porting your classes from working with *WinForms* to *Gtk#*, which is not impossible, but not trivial either. The feasibility of this would mainly depend on how good that project is architected. Do you have bussiness logic and views separated? If the answer is no, then the process will be tedious, and as hard as lengthy.

**MonoDevelop** is an IDE for C#, and Visual Studio for Mac is roughly **MonoDevelop**. It certainly works in Linux... as well as **Visual Studio Code**. So, there is no need to change anything in that front if you just need to port your code to Linux.

Okay, now, what's the road to follow? I think the best one is to try **Mono** with *WinForms*. It'd maybe involve simplify some code in the user interface part, but is certainly feasible. Just remember that you need to install **Mono**, and if your project is set to target .NET Core, then you need to create another project from scratch and set it to target .NET Framework.

Now, the specific question is that **MonoDevelop** complains about a missing `Camera_GUI.csproj`. This means that you've only picked a few files, but not the whole solution. Any IDE (Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, Rider...), would complain about the same thing. Either remove the project from the solution, or add the project with all its files to the directory in which the solution sits.

So, the answer is: don't change anything if you don't need to retarget your project. Just move to a Linux box or virtual machine, with the whole project and open it in **Visual Studio Code Rider**, **Rider**, or **MonoDevelop** it does not matter. From within the IDE, remove those projects that make no sense in Linux (i.e., windows installer), and then recompile and start the program. Polish those parts of the user interface that need tweaking and that's it.

Should you need more help, please be more specific and provide more info.